# Java Swing button text appears different

Tags: java, swing, fonts

[image: button name not clear]

I am a beginner in Java and learning Java Swing.The text of the button when at runtime appears unreadable, as shown in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihlQn.jpg . I have tried changing the font by the following lines of code. I worked on Windows 10 64-bit OS.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Button1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Button1 gui = new Button1();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton east = new JButton(" East");
        JButton west = new JButton(" West");
        JButton north = new JButton(" North");
        JButton south = new JButton(" South");
        JButton center = new JButton(" Center");

        frame.getContentPane(). add( BorderLayout.EAST, east);
        frame.getContentPane(). add( BorderLayout.WEST, west);
        frame.getContentPane(). add( BorderLayout.NORTH, north);
        frame.getContentPane(). add( BorderLayout.SOUTH, south);
        frame.getContentPane(). add( BorderLayout.CENTER, center);



        Font bigFont = new Font("serif", Font.BOLD , 10);
        east.setFont(bigFont);
        west.setFont(bigFont);
        north.setFont(bigFont);
        south.setFont(bigFont);
        center.setFont(bigFont);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: So when not setting the font, everything is okay? Try `new Font(`Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD , 10);`. (The difference is a capitalized "Serif".)

Comment: Probably your serif font is broken. I've started your example and all works fine.

Comment: And what about if you don't set the font? Is it correct then?

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36632974/131872 for a short programs that lists the fonts on your machine to see if "serif" is supported. Note, on my machine it shows "Serif". Don't know if the upper case if important.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly on my machine.

I'm going to hazard a guess that the problem is the font.  Your OS may not understand it, and thus it is rendered as it is in your screenshot.  I would try out a few other fonts, or check to see what fonts are available on your machine.